# Append item to a Json Array in Spring Boot

Tags: java, arrays, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity `Tag` like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag {
    @Id
    String name;
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Column(name = "values")
    Collection<String> values;

    public Collection<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(Collection<String> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I have designed this entity so as to have a json like this

```
{
    "name": "rbb",
    "values": [
        "Rank Banker",
        "Tank Ranker"
    ]
}
```

I have a controller like this

```
@RequestMapping("/tags")
@RestController
public class TagController {
    @Autowired
    TagsRepository tagsRepository;
    @PostMapping("/set")
    private ResponseEntity<CustomResponse> setTags(@RequestParam(value = "tag") String tag, @RequestParam(value = "values") Set<String> values){

        Tag tag1 = new Tag();
        tag1.setName(tag);
        tag1.setValues(values);

        tagsRepository.save(tag1);
        CustomResponse customResponse = new CustomResponse();
        customResponse.setStatus("Success");
        customResponse.setMessage("Successfully saved tag");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(customResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

While doing this, every time I hit this API my data will be replaced.

What I want to do is append the new values to the last json and hence I am doing it like this

```
@RequestMapping("/tags")
@RestController
public class TagController {
    @Autowired
    TagsRepository tagsRepository;
    @PostMapping("/set")
    private ResponseEntity<CustomResponse> setTags(@RequestParam(value = "tag") String tag, @RequestParam(value = "values") Set<String> values){
        Optional<Tag> tg = tagsRepository.findById(tag);
        Tag tag1;

        if(!tg.isPresent()){
            tag1 = new Tag();
            tag1.setName(tag);
            tag1.setValues(values);
        }else {
            tag1 = tg.get();
            tag1.getValues().addAll(values);
        }


        tagsRepository.save(tag1);
        CustomResponse customResponse = new CustomResponse();
        customResponse.setStatus("Success");
        customResponse.setMessage("Successfully saved tag");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(customResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

I am first finding if the value is already present and if present I am adding it to the array. But I don't think this is the right way, as finding a value becomes more tedious when the array is large. So is there any other efficient way to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Umm why arent you updating original Tag it exists ?

Comment: How can we update in JPA?

Comment: Just modify tag. Managed entity will be updated on TX commit.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Just modify instance returned by  `tagsRepository.findById(tag);`

Comment: I need to create a new one for the first time and then keep on updating it so can you please write some code to help me.

Comment: you haven't written code where it checks if value is already present in tag,values(). where is that part of code ? aren't you checking for duplicates ?

Comment: @adersh `if(!tg.isPresent())` this part checks for duplicates

Comment: @theanilpaudel and where is the problem? If tag is present, use it. If not, create new, use it and persist.

Comment: @Antoniossss this is the correct way? my concern is when array becomes large it will take more time to find and then add to the arraylist.

Comment: you need custom query for this

Comment: @theanilpaudel if it is going to be large, then you can either use raw query to insert entry with proper ID, or change it to standalone entity and insert new value with setting tag as parent.

Comment: @theanilpaudel first of all , while appending the collection when tg is present , you aren't seraching anything in the values collection , you are just appending more values to the collection , so the size of collection doesn't matter

Comment: Another way would be to lazy load that collection, so ADDING to it would not cause fetching collection. If you expect it to be large, you should lazy load it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to do this is to use existing `Tag`

```
  Optional<Tag> tg = tagsRepository.findById(tag).orElse(()=>{
        Tag newTag=new Tag();
        newTag.setName(tag);
        newTag.setValues(new HashSet<>());
   });
   //eventually chekc for duplicates and add new values OR
   // change Collection<String> to Set<String> to get rid of the problem
  tg.getValues().addAll(values);

    tagsRepository.save(tg);
```